# Android keyboard not showing when clicking on input in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom webview implemented in my android app. If I touch an input or an text area inside this webview the soft keyboard doesn't show up. I have not overriden any touchlisteners in my webview nor did I change anything in my manifest. Can anyone help me figure out why the keyboard doesn't show?

My layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <nl.AEGEE.enschede.android.AEGEEWebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progressTint="@color/aegee_blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please try to add these lines to your webview in the XML file.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was all! The strange thing is that I extend an WebView in my code and without the customwebview everything worked as expected.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for Google Forms in the web view

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko how do you solved it ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, apart from adding

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I also needed to subclass WebView and add this method

```
@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return true;
}
```

I got the solution from [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36915710) where many other solutions are proposed.

This is the entire WebView subclass, if someone wants to use it

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        BaseInputConnection baseInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
        outAttrs.imeOptions = IME_ACTION_DONE;
        outAttrs.inputType = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
        return baseInputConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To get this to work properly, I had to comment out the `onCreateInputConnection()` method.

Comment: Also, there are more constructors to add now: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#pubctors

Answer (score 1):

```
setFocusable(true)
setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
```

Comment: Please provide some sort of explanation to your answer, otherwise it gets marked as a low quality.